# Why can I not see new rows added to the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am trying to run a .NET project someone gave me that contains a database MDF file and uses LINQ queries in the C# code, such as:

```
db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
using (db)
{
   res01 r = new res01();
   r.comb_bars = 1;
   r.end_dte = b_list.Last().dteTme.Date;
   r.pers = pers;
   r.st_dte = b_list.First().dteTme.Date;
   r.sym = sym;
   db.res01s.InsertOnSubmit(r);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I see that this code runs when I debug it, but it doesn't seem like any rows were added to the database. Yet, I didn't get any errors while running the code. I am using Visual C# Express 2010. How can I see what has been added in the database MDF file that is part of the project?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Please add more detail, such as the connection string, where the .mdf file is located, etc.  And you can open the .mdf ("attach to file") file in SSMS or VS and then run queries against it.

Comment: How does `DataClasses1DataContext` look like?

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that there's a small red X on the corner of the database icon. What do I do with this?

Comment: Can you show us the connection string your app is using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is stored in the database file inside bin/Debug folder. Open that and check.

[See this for more details on connecting to compact db](http://forums.asp.net/p/1115459/1734208.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try to rebind() the grid. because the data have to be reloaded.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Is it possible to view the rows in the database through Visual C# Express 2010?

Comment: open tha database and make a select over the table to confirm if the data was added or not

Comment: I did but it doesn't seem like any data was added. I tried refreshing the db as well and still nothing there.